# What tool works with this star-shaped screw with a post in the middle?

Tags: tools, screws

What tool do I need to unscrew the fasteners shown on the metal lock on this sliding window?

[image: Window]

Comment: Kinda looks like the piece used to block a high-rise window from opening fully, to prevent accidental (or purposeful) falls from height. If this is the case and you have kids around, don't remove it and leave it unsupervised. And if the home is a rental, make sure you replace that piece later... and call someone if you're thinking about jumping!

Comment: A Dremel with a metal-cutting blade and a big flat-tip screwdriver.

Answer (score 10):

Those are tamper proof torx screws.  You will need the appropriate bit.  These are usually sold as kits of security bits.

Comment: Harbor Freight has great sets of security bits!

Comment: Thanks. Would something like this from Amazon work? They have other ones with 32 bits but would this 9 piece set likely have a bit to fit the window screws? These are 5 piece sets. Do I need this or a 6 piece set? Thanks https://www.amazon.com/McKay-Multifunction-Security-Tamper-Driver/dp/B01C7R2N9Y/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1498773010&sr=8-3&keywords=tamper+proof+torx+screws

Comment: @Help Notice the shape of the screwheads and compare that to the shape of those bits. I don't see how those two could ever fit together. You need the 6-point bits.

Comment: @DanMašek I think a source of persisting confusion is that Torx markets (or used to anyway) a system called "Torx Plus" consisting of 5 point tamper proof screws and 6 point normal screws, and no 6 point tamper proof version.

Comment: Good to know that. Would this set work? Thanks https://www.amazon.com/McKay-Multifunction-Security-Tamper-Driver/dp/B01C7R2OU2/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1498773010&sr=8-3&keywords=tamper%2Bproof%2Btorx%2Bscrews&th=1

Comment: You can often break the pin out of a security torx head by hitting it sideways with a nail set. Then you can you use a normal torx bit.

Comment: I don't want to damage the screw. Let me know if this set on Amazon would work or is there a different set you recommend which has both 5 and 6 point Torx bit. Thanks https://www.amazon.com/McKay-Multifunction-Security-Tamper-Driver/dp/B01C7R2OU2/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1498773010&sr=8-3&keywords=tamper%2Bproof%2Btorx%2Bscrews&th=1

Comment: @Help I would think those bits would be OK.  Its hard to tell the size from the pics.